# Maximum number of common zeros of n polynomials in n-1 variables

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Given $n$ quadratic polynomials in $n-1$ variables over the complex field, what is the maximum number of common zeros? Can we have $2^{n-1}-1$ common zeros? I assume that a linear combination of the polynomials is always different from zero and the number of zeros is finite.

With $4$ polynomials, the maximum is not smaller than $6$. Using a projective space $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, an example with $6$ roots is given by the polynomials.
$P_1=x_1 x_2$,
$P_2=x_1 x_3$,
$P_3=L_1 x_2+L_2 x_3$,
$P_4=(\text{a general quadratic polynomial})$,
$L_k$ being general linear polynomials.
Indeed, if $x_1=0$, then the first two polynomials are equal to zero and the remaining two polynomials in $x_2, x_3, x_4$ give four roots, which are distinct for a general choice of $L_k$ and $P_4$. If $x_2=x_3=0$, then the first three polynomials are equal to zero and the fourth polynomial in $x_1,x_4$ gives 2 additional roots.

This construction has a natural generalisation to $n$ polynomials, giving $2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}$ roots, which is about $3/4$ of the desired bound $2^{n-1}-1$.

Comment: By "polynomials over an $n-1$-dimensional space," do you mean polynomials in $n-1$ variables? Are we working over the reals, the complex numbers, some other field? What's an "intersection point" of two or more polynomials? Is it a common zero?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, let me rewrite it more geometrically: can we find $n+1$ quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^n_{\Bbb{C}}$ which intersect exactly in $2^n-1$ distinct points? For example, 4 quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ intersecting in 7 points?

Comment: You need to make some 'general position' assumption to get a good answer.  For example, when $n=5$, there are 6 linearly independent quadratic polynomials in 4 variables that vanish identically on the rational curve $(t,t^2,t^3,t^4)$, so the number of common zeros of $5$ linearly independent quadratic polynomials in 4 variables can be infinite.

Comment: You are right. I was assuming implicitly that the number of zeros is finite. Let me state explicitly in the question

Comment: For the 7 points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ lying on $4$ quadrics: Is Buchsbaum-Eisenbud relevant? The ideal of these 7 points is Gorenstein and height 3, Buchsbaum-Eisenbud says the number of minimal generators must be odd. So just having 4 quadrics is impossible. But, I don't know, perhaps some cubic appears in the saturation or something like that.

Comment: (I meant: 7 points in $\mathbb{P}^3$, not $\mathbb{P}^2$. Sorry.)

Comment: For n-1 generic polynomials, by the so-called BBK theorem, the number of common zeroes equals the mixed volume of the Newton polytopes of the polynomials. When you add the n-th polynomial the number of common zeroes cannot increase.

Comment: As a more explicit projective example, we could take $P_3 = x_2 x_3 - x_3 x_4 + x_4 x_2$, $P_4 = -x_1^2 + x_2^2 + (x_3-x_4)^2$.  So the zeroes with $x_1=0$ are $(0,(1\pm i)-\alpha^2,\pm\alpha,1)$ and$(0,(1\pm i)+\alpha^4,\pm\alpha^5,1)$, and the zeroes with $x_1\neq 0$ are $(\pm1,0,0,1)$, where $\alpha$ is a twelfth root of unity. As a more explicit non-projective example, we could replace $x_4$ with 1.

Comment: A simpler example for $n=4$ is $x^2 -1, y^2 -1, z^2-1, (x+y+z)^2-1$, which also have six common zeroes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a bound for the multiplicity of a (homogenous) almost complete intersection in Theorem 1 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.0469.pdf) by Engheta. In case of $n$ quadrics in $n-1$ variables, that bound is $2^{n-1}-(n-2)$. So for $n\geq 4$, you can not get $2^{n-1}-1$.

(In Theorem 1 there was a condition that the first $n-1$ generators form a complete intersection, but I don't think that this is serious in your case, one could always make a linear change to turn the first $n-1$ generators into a regular sequence, as the whole ideal has maximal height)

There are further improvements and examples of Engheta's bound in [this work](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2015-143-06/S0002-9939-2015-12612-3/home.html) and [this very recent work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14717).

Comment: Is the bound sharp? I looked through the papers and did not see examples in the form here.

Comment: @MattF.: I don't think it is sharp for large $n$, but I am not an expert on this topic.

Comment: Btw, I noted that bound given in the last paper cited by @HailongDao gives 3,6,12,24,51 common zeros for 3,4,5,6,7 polynomials. The example in my question gives 3,6,12,24,48 common zeros. Thus, the example is optimal for up to 6 polynomials. If the next improvement of the bound will give 48 common zeros for n=7, I will start thinking that my example is optimal.